# Ruby on Rails 4.0.0 | Routing changes from Ruby on Rails 3.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

So i have been watching a video which was introducing me to ruby on rails but the guy in the video is using ruby on rails 3 (and I am using ruby on rails 4.0.0) and when I try to use the code:

match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'

It denies it and displays this...

You should not use the `match` method in your router without specifying an HTTP method.
If you want to expose your action to both GET and POST, add `via: [:get, :post]` option.
If you want to expose your action to GET, use `get` in the router:

However I don't quite understand what it was asking me here and when i put this in the routes file

match 'new', to: 'episodes#new', via: [:get, :post]

It was unable to actually find the page i was looking for. Does anyone know what I'm supposed to type instead of

match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))' for Ruby on rails 4.0.0?

Thanks.

Comment: get 'new', to: 'episodes#new', via: [:get, :post] like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`match '/new', to: 'episodes#new', via: [:get, :post]`

I think you forgot a "/". BTW, it would be helpful to be more elaborate about "not finding" the page. Any error message?

And for understanding why you should specify HTTP methods for routing:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 1):

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
```

works for rails 3.0, but for 4.0 the missing link is the `via: [:post, :get]` statement as indicated in your rails command line.

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)' , via: [:post, :get]
```

works great and keeps your code DRY by not re-editing your routes folder every time you generate a page.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution to your problem:

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)' , via: [:post, :get]
```